# Multiple zero or one, but at least one occurrence in regex

Tags: regex

I want to validate strings that have the form:
One underscore `_`, a group of letters in `a`, `b`, `c` in alphabetical order and another underscore `_`.

Examples of valid strings are `_a_`, `_b_`, `_ac_`, `_abc_`.

I can achieve the correct validation for most cases using the regex `_a?b?c?_`, but that is still matched by `__`, which I don't want to consider valid. How can I adapt this regex so that among my zero or one characters `a?b?c?`, at least one of them must be present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `(?!_)` lookahead after the first `_`:

```
_(?!_)a?b?c?_
```

*Details*:

- `_` - an underscore
- `(?!_)` - the next char cannot be a `_`
- `a?` - an optional `a`
- `b?` - an optional `b`
- `c?` - an optional `c`
- `_` - an underscore.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxYQXU/1).

Comment: Avoiding two consecutive underscores seems a much simpler solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Freguglia Yes, because you avoid the need to duplicate `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a positive lookahead:

```bash
_(?=[abc])a?b?c?_
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1VpFMG/2)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `_`: Match a `_`
- `(?=[abc])`: Positive lookahead to assert that there is a letter `a` or `b` or `c`
- `a?b?c?`: Match optional `a` followed by `b` followed by `c`
- `_`: Match a `_`

PS: Positive lookahead assertions are usually more efficient than negative lookahead (as evident from steps taken on regex101 webste).

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd chip in an alternative if one uses Python for this with PyPi's regex module which support what is called approximate “fuzzy” matching:

```
^_(abc){d<=2}_$
```

The pattern means:

- `^_` - Match start-line anchor and leading underscore;
- `(abc){d<=2}` - Match 'abc' in order and allow for up to just two deletions;
- `_$` - Match trailing undescore and end-line anchor.

---

```
import regex as re
l = ["_a_", "_b_", "_ac_",  "_abc_", "", "__", "_ca_"]
print([bool(re.search(r'^_(abc){d<=2}_$', s)) for s in l])
```

Prints:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option if a lookbehind is supported is looking back after the match, asserting not `__`

```
_a?b?c?_(?<!__)
```

**Explanation**

- `_` Match literally
- `a?b?c?` Match an optional *a* or *b* or *c*
- `_` Match literally
- `(?<!__)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `__` directly to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z7t7Gp/1)

If supported using SKIP FAIL getting `__` out of the way:

```
__(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|_a?b?c?_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L1vWFl/1)